# How can I assign json array into cell string?

Tags: objective-c, json, iphone, collectionview

I have sample json data as below and I would like to assign these data in my cell list. Currently my result will show wrongly in attribute name.:-

```
{
        "attribute_group_name" = Color;
        "attribute_name" =         (
            Black,
            White,
            Gold,
            Red
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Service;
        "attribute_name" =         (
            "Free Shipping",
            Insurance
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Telco;
        "attribute_name" =         (
            Digi,
            Maxis,
            Celcom
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Material;
        "attribute_name" =         (
            Wood
        );
    },
        {
        "attribute_group_name" = Brand;
        "attribute_name" =         (
            Apple,
            Mi,
            Gome,
            HuaWei
        );
    },
```

And here is my current output. I have wrong attribute name in my list (duplicate data) but the header is correct.

[image]

Here is my code in cellForItemAtIndexPath and numberOfItemsInSection. Appreciated your help:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FilterItemCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:FilterItemCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //HOW to set cell.attribute_name here?

    NSLog(@"1 - %@",(NSArray *)[self.filterItem[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"attribute_name"]);
    //    Result in 1 - (
    //              Black,
    //              White,
    //              Gold,
    //              Red
    //              )
    //    How can I set it accordingly in cell?

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     return ((NSArray *)[self.filterItem[section] valueForKey:@"attribute_name"]).count;
}
```

Comment: in self.filterItem array you stored all your data right?

Comment: @RB1509,yup, all stored inside.

Comment: and you used collectionview in tableview right?

Comment: Is collectionview only. Header is another cell and attribute_name is under another cell.

Comment: only use collection view than ok.i will try to solve that

Comment: @RB1509, Thx bro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170056/discussion-between-rb1509-and-test-87).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  cell.attribute_name=[[self.filterItem[section] valueForKey:@"attribute_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: great. My code is working now. i edited to   cell.attribute_name=[[self.filterItem[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"attribute_name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];. Thx for your help!